# Always a new variable when multiple returns

Tags: go

I'm facing a wierd problem with Golang.

On `init()` function, i want to assign a value to my variable that was declared outside this function.

But to assign the value to this var, i need to get
    `error`
to check if everything is ok.

Here is the code:

```
var retryValue time.Duration

func init() {
    retryValue, err := time.ParseDuration(retries)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("retries value is invalid", err)
    }
}

func a(){
    fmt.Println(retryValue)
}
```

And i get the compiling error:
    `retryValue declared and not used`

I need to change `init()` to this:

```
func init() {
    var err error
    retryValue, err = time.ParseDuration(retries)

if err != nil {

log.Fatal("retries value is invalid", err)
    }
}
```

There is another way to solve this problem?
    `:=`
always create a new variable if one of the variables are already declared? It's about variable golang's sope?

Thanks!

Comment: s/:=/=/ and please: Take the Tour of Go tour.golang.org.

Comment: You are getting this error because you are not using `retryValue` that is declared outside of `init`'s scope. Declaring `retryValue :=` inside `init`'s scope means that you are instantiating a new variable called `retryValue` that is accessible only inside of this function.

Comment: @AndreaM16 there is no more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic ways to do this.  You found one:

```
var retryValue time.Duration

func init() {
    var err error
    retryValue, err = time.ParseDuration(retries)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("retries value is invalid", err)
    }
}
```

A slightly shorter method would be:

```
var retryValue = func() time.Duration {
    rv, err := time.ParseDuration(retries)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("retries value is invalid", err)
    }
    return rv
}()
```

But better than either of these, would be to just specify the value directly, rather than parsing it:

```
var retryValue = 15 * time.Minute // or whatever value you want
```

Answer (score -2):

Your fix is indeed the shortest way to do this, and no there is not another way to solve the issue.

This problem is rare enough that it is not really an issue in practice, after all it is only one more (short) line.